# How can I prevent auto-mounting of a partition in fstab?

Tags: boot, mount, kubuntu, fstab, etc

Previously, I prevented auto-mounting of a particular partition at boot by the following line in `/etc/fstab`

```
UUID=<alphanumeric> /media/windowsHDD ntfs user,noauto 0 0
```

At some point in the last year, this failed, and the partition was automatically mounted on boot. I attempted the following, which also failed.

```
/dev/sda1 /media/windowsHDD ntfs user,noauto 0 0
```

Thinking that perhaps I was bitten by [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-volume-manager/+bug/120829), I removed `user`, but that also failed.

```
UUID=<alphanumeric> /media/windowsHDD ntfs noauto 0 0
```

Is there a way to prevent auto-mounting in fstab?

Comment: @Jobin I'll try commenting out the entire line. Oddly enough, another `noauto` entry in there still works `/dev/sdb1 /media/3030-3030/ vfat user,noauto 0 0`.

Comment: In the bug report that you mentioned yourself, people suggest to use another mountpoint than one inside `/media`. This folder may get treated in a special way by Ubuntu, and some automount mechanism may mount it even though your `/etc/fstab` says otherwise. Suggestion: move the mountpoint to somewhere else (`/mnt/windowsHDD` or whatever) and try again. Don't forget to create the directory that you specify as mount point.

Comment: @MalteSkoruppa I tried changing the mountpoint to `/mnt/windowsHDD`. I forgot to create the directory (and I don't want it to automount anyway), but upon restart it was created and mounted there.

Comment: @Jobin commenting out the entire line results in automatic mounting at `/media/sparhawk/windowsHDD`. Oddly enough, when I do specify the location to mount in fstab, the files are marked green with `ls -l`. However, when I comment everything out, they are just a normal colour.

Answer (score 9):

In order to avoid this issue make sure of 2 things:

1. The partition is **not** mounted in /media
2. The the name of the target
   mount directory is different than the partition label value

---

Check entry in /etc/fstab:

```
user@raspberrypi:/ $ cat /etc/fstab
/dev/sda1     /media/st1       ntfs-3g noauto,rw         0       0
```

Check the label of the partition:

```
user@raspberrypi:/ $ sudo ntfslabel -f /dev/sda1 
st1
```

Since the name of target mount directory (/media/**st1**) equals the partition label (**st1**), the partition will continue to mount automatically despite the noauto parameter in /etc/fstab.

---

Let's do something to avoid the automatic mount. Create a new directory in /mnt:

```
user@raspberrypi:/ $ sudo mkdir /mnt/testdir
```

Edit the /etc/fstab entry:

```
/dev/sda1     /mnt/testdir       ntfs-3g auto,rw         0       0
```

Finally change the label of the partition and reboot:

```
user@raspberrypi:/ $ sudo ntfslabel /dev/sda1 "new_label"

user@raspberrypi:/ $ sudo reboot
```

The partition shouldn't be mounted automatically anymore.

Comment: Unfortunately I moved to Arch Linux a few years ago, so I can't really comment on whether this works or not. This problem went away with the migration and/or a KDE Plasma update. However, welcome to StackExchange and thank you for posting this answer. Hopefully it will be useful to others! (P.S. have an upvote.)

Comment: "Since the name of target mount directory (/media/st1) equals the partition label (st1), the partition will continue to mount automatically despite the noauto parameter in /etc/fstab."  .... but why?  It's been a long time since I've used labels, but this seems silly when it's explicitly set to noauto.

Comment: did you mean to mount `/mnt/testdir` with `auto` and not `noauto`?

Answer (score -3):

Try addind this to `/etc/fstab`.  Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
/dev/sdaX /media/external-noauto ext4 user,noauto 0 0
```

Or you can use [PySDM](http://pysdm.sourceforge.net/)

Make sure you replace X with your device ID.

Comment: Instead of noauto, what if the line is commented?

Comment: @Mitch Are you saying to add that line to fstab? Your second and third sentences suggest to run it as a command. Also, it seems like it's essentially identical to my original line, except it's ext4 when my disk is really ntfs. I want to be able to mount it at the listed location if needed, just not automatically.

Comment: @Jobin I'll reply in the main comments below my question.

Comment: Add to fstab, will disable auto mounting.  It's slightly different than your original, where you have to add noauto after the drives name.  `/dev/sdaX /media/external-noauto ntfs user,noauto 0 0`  Let me know.

Comment: That didn't work either. Upon restart, the partition automatically mounted at `/media/external-noauto` instead.

Comment: Have you tried PySDM?

Comment: @Mitch No, but from the screenshots, it looks like it can't prevent automatic mounting.