# Ownership/permission problem with automounting exfat drive

Tags: permissions, mount, automount, rsync, exfat

I'm new to Linux and am having problems automounting an exFat-formatted partition on a Lacie-disk in Ubuntu 16.04.

I installed `exfat-fuse` and `exfat-utils` and could then mount manually using:

```
sudo mount -t exfat /dev/sdb2 /media/maria/Lexfat
```

The exfat disk would not automount, however, so I edited `/etc/fstab` (not sure what the options mean, though, so perhaps the problem is there...?):

```
sudo nano /etc/fstab
/dev/sdb2 /media/maria/Lexfat exfat defaults,auto,umask=000,users,rw 0 0
```

(I tried to get an UUID using `blkid`, but this does not list my exfat disk)

Now, the disk is automounted when I startup Ubuntu, but owned by root user.

So I need to give password to unmount it and am not allowed to remount with GUI. I am not allowed to change ownership using `chown`, either.

I have transferred files from a remote server to the disk using `rsync`, which works fine except that I get

```
failed to set times-error
```

I'm guessing that both the mounting and `rsync` issues are ownership/permission problems, but I don't understand how to fix it. Any ideas, please?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

### Automount exfat with user permissions

When specifying the auto option, the devices gets automatically mounted at boot time with root-permissions. The proper options for exfat are described in the [mount.exfat](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/en/man8/mount.exfat.8.html) manpage. Change the `/etc/fstab` entry to:

```
/dev/sdb1 /media/maria/Lexfat exfat defaults,uid=1000,gid=1000 0 0
```

The defaults options (rw, suid, dev, exec, auto, nouser, and async) are good enough in most cases. The proper `uid` and `gid` for your current user can be obtained by

```
$ id $USER
uid=1000(yourusername) gid=1000(yourusername) groups=1000(yourusername),4(adm),24(cdrom),...
```

For a different user name, replace `$USER` with the desired user name.

Validate the `/etc/fstab` entry before rebooting the system by testing the entry:

```
$ sudo mount /media/maria/Lexfat
```

If the entry is wrong of faulty in any way, the system boot will stop working and you might need to fix it with the [Ubuntu live system](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#1-overview).

### chown in exfat

Regarding the `chown` problems and errors: exfat does not support user permissions. So using `chown` on a file inside exfat will always fail:

```
$ sudo chown root:root /media/maria/Lexfat/test.txt
chown: changing ownership of ‘test.txt’: Function not implemented
```

### rsync into exfat

The problem with time-stamps and permissions are the same as the ownership issue: exfat does not support it. But rsync will still work, just don't use the `-a` option.

```
$ rsync -r /from/here /media/maria/Lexfat
```

Comment: That suggested fstab totally Bjorked my system. Thanks.

Comment: @ShawnMcDonald I don't believe, a mount point in `/etc/fstab` is able to do that... But adding a not existing mount point to fstab will break the system boot. Adding the [`noauto`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/421585/how-can-i-prevent-auto-mounting-of-a-partition-in-fstab) option will e.g. work for usb sticks

Comment: @ShawnMcDonald The same thing happened to me when I had an drive failure. I learned the hard way that any additional drives I mount all need the "nofail" attribute added to the entry so there is "no failure due to error on boot" -  https://man.archlinux.org/man/fstab.5#DESCRIPTION. I do this for all USB external drives.

Comment: @SimonSudler I used to have issues with rsync to EXFAT drives, so used different switches to overcome the Linux to EXFAT permissions and groups issue:    rsync -vrltD --progress --stats /source/a/ /dest/a  https://www.scivision.dev/rsync-to-exfat-drive/ 
 Couple that with the UID and GID entries for accessing the drive and it's win win. 
"UUID=EAEB-D1B6  /mnt/mybook     exfat   defaults,uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=002,nofail     0       2"
6TB running on a raspberry pi 4